# Why does Flow require annotation of parameter of exported function?

Tags: flowtype

Following code ([Flow playground](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVUCuA7AxgFwEs5swBDACgAcBKMAbwF9UBbOAE0xgFMA6bgB5U4AJ3wBnMAF5yQA)):

```flow
/* @flow */

function a(p) {}
module.exports = a
```

throws exception

```
3: function a(p) {}
              ^ parameter `p`. Missing annotation
```

Why is that? I'd expect that type `any` would be automatically assumed for the parameter `p`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://flowtype.org/docs/type-annotations.html#module-boundaries):

> ### Module Boundaries
>
> Flow requires annotations at the boundaries of modules. This allows Flow to analyze modules in isolation which improves the performance of checking types across module boundaries. We’ve found that this helps to improve the self-documenting nature of module interfaces as well.