# Why does Flow sometimes require annotations in functions/methods?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have two components, both are using flow and declared as

```
extends React.Component<Props, State>
```

But in one I get an error,

```
componentDidCatch = (error, info) => {
                            ^^^^^ error. Missing annotation
```

and in component #2, I don't.

At first, I thought perhaps its because component #2 is used by another component that is also flow-checked.  But then I realised that this is true for component #1 too.

I don't see any obvious reason for this different behavior, and I'm curious why.  Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your code for the two components in question?

Comment: [Looks like the same issue described here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41419511/why-does-flow-require-annotation-of-parameter-of-exported-function) which I believe applies to methods of exported classes as well